# How can i parse the return value(s) from python -c "import mypackage"

Tags: python

Case # 1 : No values are returned , means success

Case # 2: get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named mypackage
```

Comment: What is the use-case here? And parse from which language?

Comment: parse for result values, which are 0 and non zero ( like 256 )

Comment: What language are you trying to parse it in?

Comment: bash is what i am using to parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, don't.

In longer, if you need to detect what packages are installed, at least do something like:

```
try:
    import mypkg
    print "can import"
except:
    import "can't import"
```

Or check the return value:

```
$ python -c "import foo" 2> /dev/null; echo $?
1
$ python -c "import sys" 2> /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Comment: @kamal: Note that the non-zero return value just indicates "something went wrong". That may be an `ImportError` or it may be something else (e.g. your command may have a typo and say `improt` rather than `import`, or there may be an error in the module being imported).